# How to download partial s3 aws cli using the terminal? Its a 1 TB json/xml file, I only want 100-200MB of sequential, numbered files

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is what I have tried:
 aws s3 cp s3://bucket name/folder ~/downloads --range bytes=0-200000000. I get an unknown options range error.

Please provide me some guidance. I have about 1 TB of data, but I would like to do a partial download of about 100 MB of sequential, numbered files to my external hard drive. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform this for a single file, you could use the AWS S3 CLI api:

`aws s3api get-object --bucket YOUR_BUCKET --key YOUR_FOLDER/KEY --range 100 TARGET_FILE_NAME`

**Note the use of `s3api` instead of `s3`.**

The `range` parameter here will determine which range of bytes of your file you'd like to download.

Two weeks ago, however, AWS announced `Amazon S3 Select`.

> Amazon S3 Select is now available in Preview. S3 Select is a new Amazon S3 capability designed to pull out only the data you need from an object, dramatically improving the performance and reducing the cost of applications that need to access data in S3.

It's currently in preview but you can opt-in for it and once you're approved should be able to use this API.

Click [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-s3-select-is-now-available-in-limited-preview/) to find out more.

### EDIT

You can use the `sync` api operation of the S3 service to download contents of a bucket.

A possible solution would be `aws s3 sync s3://bucketname .`

To include or exclude certain files, use the flags `--include "*.json"` and `--exclude "*test.json"` respectively

Comment: Tom, thank you very much. What is the value for KEY? Is that the aws access key id?

Comment: That would be the object key, so if your file is located directly inside the bucket it would just be the file name. If your file is inside a folder inside the bucket it would be folder/filename. If this answer helped you come to a solution, please mark it accepted so it can help others as well.

Comment: I am still off. I am not able to save it to a folder (it creates a file for me) and I am not able to download more than one file at a time. I have sequential, numbered set of .json files that I'd like to download all at once (about 100MB). Thank you so much for all your help so far.

Comment: Unfortunately this api doesn't have a `get-objects` method so it has to happen one at a time. An easier solution would be to use the aws sdk in a programming language and write some logic to loop over your bucket contents and download it all at once.

Comment: Is there a way to maybe set a range for the files, say I have 100.json thru 200.json. How might I pull them at once?

Comment: I have python installed. I am not that familiar with any language. Just picking stuff up here and there. Ultimately I just need to figure out how to do bulk downloads from my S3.

Comment: I ran the s3 sync, I get a Errno20, Not a directory.... Is there a way to set a range to limit to only 100MB?

Comment: Please try to get the sync working first until you see it downloading, you can ctrl+c out of it just to see if it works. see the docs here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: Now use `--exclude` to filter out the files you don't want to download. You can use wildcards to select multiple files at once, you can also use multiple `--exclude` statements.

Comment: what would be an example of a wildcard to grab sequential files starting with e.g. 1000 and ending with 3000? And then putting them in downloads/JSON directory.

Comment: The reason I am asking for it this way is I have 1TB of files that begin with 20010000001 and end with 20150000001. I do not want all that. I just need about 100-200MB worth of sequential files.

Comment: Since you mentioned 100.json through 200.json I thought `aws s3 sync` would do the trick. In that case you'll need a programming language and write some logic to download them basic on a variable keyname.

Comment: I did aws s3 sync then terminated the process, and now I can not find the files.

Comment: Terminating was just to test if you were no longer getting the Errno20, if you want it to finish downloading, just don't terminate it.